# Smallest subring of rationals containing $ p/q$, where $ p$ and $q $ are relatively prime

Tags: ring-theory

I am trying to find the smallest subring of rationals containing $p/q$, where p,q are relatively prime. I am constructing the subring from $p/q $ and I think rationals of form $pZ/q^k$ where k is whole number is the answer.  Am I wrong? Is there any general solution for $p/q$?

Edit: I am looking for a general solution for any $p/q$. There is no constraint that 1 should be in the subring.

Comment: Does a ring for you have a multiplicative identity element?

Comment: You mean $\frac{p}{q}$ is a fixed rational number, and you're looking for the smallest ring generated with it? That's what it feels like, just making sure.